# generalized cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

If I have a generalized cohomology theory $E$, then $E^n(X) = [\sum^{-n}X, E]$.  I would like to know what $[\sum^{-n}*, E]$ looks like for $*$ a point.  We can assume that $E$ is a nice $CW$ spectra if necessary.  What I want to do is describe $MU^*(*)$, where $MU$ is formed from $MU(n)$ the Thom space and suspensions.

Comment: Would it be $[\mathbb{R}^\infty_+, E_n]$?  Is there a nicer thing I could say?

Comment: I don't know what kind of answer you're looking for. At a point you get the homotopy groups of the spectrum representing the generalized cohomology theory. For $MU$ you get the cobordism ring of almost complex manifolds (http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Complex_bordism).